# Profile Manager - Autonomous Single App Mode

Tags: ios, mdm, osx-server, apple-profile-manager

I am adding autonomous single app mode to a group of applications that I develop. I've got everything working using the Meraki MDM; but I would rather use Apple Profile Manager if possible.

The only option I can see in Profile Manager is to lock to one app (not autonomous single app mode).

**Does Apple Profile Manager support autonomous single app mode?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profile Manager now supports this feature (tested in OS X Server 5.0.4).

The configuration profile for Autonomous Single App Mode has to be created within "Device Groups->Settings"; the option is not available when creating a profile within "Users->Settings"